# My python script turn off touchpad and power button why?

Tags: python, linux

I use KDE on Manjaro linux. I have this script in python to turn off touchpad:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from subprocess import call

class Example(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):               

    qbtn = QPushButton('On', self)
    qbtn.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonOn)
    qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
    qbtn.move(25, 50)  

    qbtn = QPushButton('Off', self)
    qbtn.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonOff)
    qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
    qbtn.move(125, 50) 

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 100)
    self.setWindowTitle('Touchpad On/Off')    
    self.show()

def handleButtonOn(self, event):
    print ('On')
    call(["synclient", "touchpadoff=0"])
    call(["notify-send", "Your touchpad is set to ON"])
    self.destroy()

def handleButtonOff(self, event):
    print ('Off')
    call(["synclient", "touchpadoff=1"])
    call(["notify-send", "Your touchpad is set to OFF"])
    self.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's works almost perfect (turn off my touchpad) but when I start script it's turn off my power button so I can't turn off computer by this button.
There is a problem with Yakuake too, can't write in this terminal. Finally i've start some other terminal for example "konsole" and turn off computer by shutdown command.
I'm new in python. How to make this work OK. I need turn off my touchpad, I use external mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue with power button, but I found out that self.destroy() is causing your script to freeze in some corrupted-not-responding-to-SIGINT state. Replacing self.destroy() with self.close() makes it work on my machine.

Please try replacing self.destroy() with self.close().

Comment: It seems to work OK now. Thanks. I wander why .destroy() generate errors?